# Some priors for these parameters with a preferential range, and a proposal?

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings

I have the following parameters, with a specified range, but with also a preferential range of values. I'm looking for some priors for them. Later on, I will have to use a Metropolis-Hastings type of algorithm to get an estimation of the posterior.  The likelihood will be similar to a normal type density.
If possible, could you also suggest me a proposal density for the M-H step?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Parameter}&\text{Preference Values from previous 'studies'}& \text{Range}\\ \hline
\beta & 0.95 \text{ upwards} & ]0,1[\\ \hline
    \delta & 0.025\text{ up to }0.05 & ]0,1[ \\ \hline
    \eta & 1.004 \text{ up to } 1.006& 
 ]1,+\infty[ \\ \hline
    \theta & 0.30 \text{ up to } 0.38 & ]0,1[\\ \hline
    \rho &  0.99\text{ upwards } & ]-1,1[\\ \hline
\end{array}